# Manually generate ActiveX wrapper after TLBIMP-ed dlls?

Tags: .net, com, activex, tlbimp

I have several ActiveX components that needed to be accessed from a C# project.

I can import them via Visual Studio's add reference dialog, which will also automatically generate wrappers class. (i.e. `ABCLib` and `AxABCLib`)

I know that I can generate the primary interop assembly manually by running `TLBIMP /primary` on each individual OCX file but I could not find a way to generate the ActiveX wrapper unless I do it via Visual Studio user interface.

Is there a command-line version that generate the ActiveX wrapper in the .NET SDK?

I want to generate the `AxABCLib` version from the PIA I got from TLBIMP manually. (i.e. setting namespaces, output dll filenames etc.) Is it possible?

Comment: So you answered your own question, does that mean it is not a good question or answer? Why not leave your question open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh... found it after looking at the folder where TLBIMP belongs.

It's called `AxImp`.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\AxImp.exe`

So basically, to generate a PIA DLL in your own customized namespace:

1. Register your OCX

   `regsvr32 abc.ocx`
2. Generate a strong name key pair for you ocx by running

   `sn -k`
3. Run TLBIMP and specify the desired namespace

   `tlbimp abc.ocx /primary /keyfile:abc.snk /out:abc.dll /namespace:MyNamespace`
4. Run AXIMP on the ocx and use the `rcw` switch to use your own manully generated PIA DLL.

   `aximp abc.ocx /source /rcw:abc.dll`

That should do it.

There are however some problems with ancient TLBs being imported. I am not sure how to fix that yet.