# Wrap ActiveX to Intercept Calls (ActiveX Proxy wrapper)

Tags: mfc, proxy, activex, dynamic-proxy

I have a deeply ingrained ActiveX control in our system which I would like to learn about / fix!

I am thinking about wrapping this MFC dll with a transparent proxy class that will intercept the member etc.

HOW can this be approached in MFC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by generating an ActiveX wrapper using AxImp, then modifying the generated wrapper with your intercept code.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446121/manually-generate-activex-wrapper-after-tlbimp-ed-dlls) for details on manually generating the wrapper.