# Declaring COM interface pointer without header file

Tags: c#, c++, com

I am writing an application using C# and WinForms. I have an ActiveX control provided by a third party. I drag the ActiveX control to a form, and get an instance of the class (call it "Widget") that the control implements.

Now I need to pass an interface pointer, IWidget, from C# into legacy C++ code. I plan to put the C++ code in a dll and call it from C# using P/Invoke. The problem is I don't know how to provide the IWidget definition to the C++ code. The original authors of the C++ code had header files (say widget.h), so they could #include widget.h, and declare an IWidget pointer.

I don't have the .h (and can't get it). I only have the ActiveX. So how can I declare an IWidget pointer in my dll?

My only idea so far is to create an IDL file from the ActiveX dll. Is that a reasonable approach?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Use the #import directive.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Does the IDL have a definition for IWidget?  Post that and you should be able to get the C# equivalent.

Comment: #import looks promising. I will try that when I get a chance in a couple days. Thank you everyone for the responses.

Comment: #import worked great. Hans, if you care to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try import metadata from ActiveX with tlbimp.exe which create managed assembly and IWidget should be there. If you create class with this managed version of interface and [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)], it should pass through to  ActiveX.

See howto for tlbimp [activex-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446121/manually-generate-activex-wrapper-after-tlbimp-ed-dlls)